# SpringBoot - Junit test not Rollingback using JdbcTemplate for H2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit4, h2

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

Technologies used:

Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, Spring 4.3.4.RELEASE, Thymeleaf 2.1.5.RELEASE, Tomcat Embed 8.5.6, Maven 3, Java 8

I have this test, that is failing, because Junit test is not rolling back the insert `java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<1> but was:<2>`

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={PersistenceConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class JdbcGuardianRepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcGuardianRepository repository;

    @Test   
    public void testGetAllGuardians() throws DataAccessException, SQLException {        
        assertEquals(1, repository.getAllGuardians(null).size());
    }


    @Test
    @Rollback
    public void testInsetGuardian() throws DataAccessException, SQLException {

        Guardian newGuardian = new Guardian();

        newGuardian.setDescription("bob desc");
        newGuardian.setEmail("bob@gmail.com");
        newGuardian.setId(Sequencer.getNextVal());
        newGuardian.setMobile("123456789");
        newGuardian.setName("bob");
        newGuardian.setSurName("bob surname");

        assertNotEquals(-1, repository.insert(newGuardian));
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it "failing" exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Rollback` annotation works only if transaction management happens through Jpa/Hibernate/JdbcTemplate (the annotation influence on transaction only if the transaction is managed by some `PlatformTransactionManager`).

It looks like `JdbcGuardianRepository` uses plain jdbc access (or something like that) and spring cannot know anything about your transactions.

Consider using JPA to manage transactions and you'll solve the problem.

Alternatively you can annotate your test class with `@Sql("/clean-db.sql")` and provide some cleanup sql code inside `clean-db.sql`. Spring will run this script before every test run.
Consider adding more information about `JdbcGuardianRepository` if this does not solve your problem.